# Kotlin NullPointerException Issue

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making app with Google Map but i have a problem with permissions. Someone can help me please? While Android 10 has no problem, Android 9 has this problem.
These 106-115 row's codes

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),1)

        }else{
            locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2,2f,locationListener)
            mMap.clear()
            var lastLocation = locationManager!!.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            var lastUserLocation = LatLng(lastLocation!!.latitude,lastLocation!!.longitude)
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastUserLocation,17f))
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPZr5.jpg)

Comment: Since `getLastKnownLocation()` frequently returns `null`, using `!!` is not a good idea.

Comment: what is your suggestion for this line?

Comment: I suggest that you check for `null` and deal with that case. `lastLocation?.let { var lastUserLocation = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude); mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastUserLocation,17f))` }`, for example. You also need to have `locationListener` handle when you get location events and update the map then too, at least for the first location if `getLastKnownLocation()` returned `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)